# Apply two different colors as a gradient to different words in <li> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to render the fizz buzz function in an unordered list, with each word corresponding to a different color ('fizz'-- green, 'buzz'--blue) like so:

[image: fizz buzz]

I'm successfully rendering "fizz" and "buzz" in their colors on their own, but when it comes to rendering the "fizzbuzz" line, the entire background of the `<li>`
is split between green and blue instead of only the individual words.

Here's the css selector responsible for "fizzbuzz":

```
li:nth-child(3n + 0):nth-child(5n + 0) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 50%, blue 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

I tried modifying the `display` property on the parent `<ul>` to "inline" but that doesn't fix the problem:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: in-line;
  
}
```

I'm trying to do this in pure css without modifying my html/js. Here's the code:

```js
const unorderedList = Array.from(document.querySelector("ul").children);

function fizzbuzz(elements) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var result = "";
    var line = i + 1;
    if (line % 3 === 0) result += "Fizz";        
    if (line % 5 === 0) result += "Buzz";
    if (result.length ===0) result = line;
    elements[i].innerText = result;
    }
}

fizzbuzz(unorderedList)
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: in-line;
  
}

li:nth-child(3n + 0) {
  color: green;
}

li:nth-child(5n + 0) {
  color: blue;
}

li:nth-child(3n + 0):nth-child(5n + 0) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 50%, blue 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>FizzBuzz</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `width:fit-content;`

```js
const unorderedList = Array.from(document.querySelector("ul").children);

function fizzbuzz(elements) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var result = "";
    var line = i + 1;
    if (line % 3 === 0) result += "Fizz";        
    if (line % 5 === 0) result += "Buzz";
    if (result.length ===0) result = line;
    elements[i].innerText = result;
    }
}

fizzbuzz(unorderedList)
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: in-line;
  
}

li:nth-child(3n + 0) {
  color: green;
}

li:nth-child(5n + 0) {
  color: blue;
}

li:nth-child(3n + 0):nth-child(5n + 0) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 50%, blue 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color:transparent;
  width:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>FizzBuzz</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```